# Is there a way to autofill WorksheetFunction.Sum down the column?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have the following code to Sum a range of cells, but I want it to autofill down the column, but when I add that code it autfills the result of the sum. I also tried using .Formula, but I couldn't get it to work with the Dims, but I imagine that would let me use autofill. the Dims will be different each time the Macro is run and the number of rows will be different too.

```
Dim fCell As Range 
Dim fDate As Range
Dim lDate As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set fcell = ActiveCell 'this is J2
Set fDate = Range("C2")
Set lDate = ActiveCell ' this is I2
Set rng = Range([fDate], [lDate]) 

fCell.Select
fCell = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
```

Comment: Are you going auofill the result of WorksheetFunction.Sum (it is a value/string..) or formula?

Comment: I want it to be the formula that autofills, but when I use WorkSheetFuntion.Sum it is the result that autfofills. I want it to be a value.

Comment: What's the expected formula?

Comment: I need it to SUM the range of cells C2:J2, but this range will be different each time the Macro runs

Comment: I have tried to do it like this, but I can't get the Syntax right

Comment: fCell.Formula = "=SUM" & rng.Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both fcell and lDate are being assigned ActiveCell, but the comment indicates that lDate is 1 x Column before the ActiveCell so I have made this adjustment, otherwise your formula would be circular and have an issue.

I believe this should produce what you are after.
It puts a formula in the selected Cell to SUM everything from cell C2 until the column to the left of the selected cell.

```
Public Sub ApplyFormula()
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim fDate As Range
    Dim lDate As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set fCell = ActiveCell                          ' Current Cell Selected
    Set fDate = Range("C2")
    Set lDate = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1)  ' this is 1 x Column before the Active Cell
    Set rng = Range(fDate, lDate)

    fCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & REPLACE(rng.Address, "$", "") & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Yes, I have been able to do this myself, but my problem is I then want to autofill down the column, but the formula uses Absolute referencing. So the autofill always uses fDate & lDate. I need C2:I2 type referencing and I don't know how to change it to that. Any Idea?

Comment: If you want the formula to exclude the $, then you could wrap it in a replace.
i.e.

fCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & REPLACE(rng.Address, "&", "") & ")"

Comment: Sorry dude I don't understand, that hasn't changed it to relative reference

Comment: Ah, you hade typed & when you meant $ - I have it sorted now. thanks x

Comment: Sorry about that, I've also updated the original answer to reflect this change